# Get 'Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined' error on jHipster

Tags: java, node.js, npm, jhipster, jhipster-registry

While running [jHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) command, I got the following errors:

```
+ jhipster axon --skip-git --blueprint cst
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! No custom sharedOptions found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-cst at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-cst
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at new module.exports (/Users/.../jhipster/generator-jhipster-cst/generators/subgenerator-base.js:27:49)
    at new module.exports (/Users/.../jhipster/generator-jhipster-cst/generators/aws/index.js:3:18)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:673:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:645:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:74:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:62:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
Emitted 'error' event on Environment instance at:
    at Environment.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:293:12)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:647:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:74:31
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
```

I tried to update npm and jHipster, but there was another problem with upgrading jHipster:

```
~ sudo jhipster upgrade

INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
INFO! Executing jhipster:upgrade
This seems to be an app blueprinted project with jhipster 6.6.0 bug (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11045), you should pass --blueprints to jhipster upgrade commmand.
Error: This seems to be an app blueprinted project with jhipster 6.6.0 bug (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11045), you should pass --blueprints to jhipster upgrade commmand.
    at module.exports.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1590:15)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/upgrade/index.js:95:18)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:673:23)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:645:19)
    at instantiateAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:729:30)
    at Environment.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:758:12)
    at runYoCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:53:13)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/cli/cli.js:178:17)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/commander/index.js:413:31)
    at Command._parseCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/commander/index.js:914:14)
```

NPM: 6.14.8
Node: 12.16.1
jhipster: 6.10.3
Java: Tested with 13.0.2 & 11.0.8

---

## Updated

The part of the code from which the error originated ( 'replace' of undefined ):

```
const configuration = {
    ...opts,
    ...this.getAllJhipsterConfig(this, true)
};
this.baseName = configuration.baseName;
this.serverPort = configuration.serverPort;
this.packageName = configuration.packageName;
this.rootPackageName = this.packageName.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');
```

Could you explain to me, how can I fix the above problem, please?

Comment: Could you explain  "--blueprint cst" ?

Comment: cst blueprint, consist own templates & functionality. @GaëlMarziou

Comment: OK so how people without knowing this custom blueprint could help you?